# Go - VSCode - Modules Extremely Slow

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, module

I am trying to work with Go on VSCode. I do not want to keep all of my go code in one place, so i use modules. VSCode is now extremely slow to load any definitions, auto complete, or go to definition. Are there any solutions to this or I am I stuck between working in the GO_PATH or dealing with a slow IDE?

Comment: I can't tell you much, but I felt the same way.. tried vscode and atom for a bit, and then moved to emacs (spacemacs) every editor has their own issues.. unfortunately handling of go code is one of the big ones... esspecially if you work with golang in monorepos

Answer (score 0):

[Using go modules](https://blog.golang.org/using-go-modules) should not make your IDE slow.
Instead of GOPATH, it will load said modules in their own `pkg/mod` paths on your computer.

The only reason it would be slow is if said path is not on your local drive, but on a network drive with lots of latency.

Make sure to use the latest VSCode + [vscode-go](https://github.com/golang/vscode-go), as well as the latest [gopls plugin](https://github.com/golang/tools/blob/master/gopls/README.md).

Comment: The path is on my local drive. VSCode and plugins are up to date. When I hover over a local variable, the details come up immediately. When I hover over a variable in a module path, it takes about 5 seconds to load.

Comment: Yeah, I double checked by moving my project to the GOPATH and removing the module stuff. This fixes it. This should be easy enough to reproduce if you'd like.

Comment: @WreckFish I do not reproduce that on my workstation. Everything is reasonably fast (but my project is not huge)

Comment: Nor is mine, so not sure what it could be. Regardless, at this point I have given up and am working within the GOPATH

Comment: @WreckFish OK. I will leave this answer for other readers, then.